# Is there a way to make Entity Framework SQLite more performant in Debug mode?

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, maui

I am developing a .NET MAUI App that uses EntityFramework with SQLite to store data on the device. The implementation works perfectly fine, but it painfully slow when I deploy the software to my test phones. If I deploy it as Release, it is lightning fast. Executing code in Debug bring additional overhead, but I wanted to ask, if there are tweaks to improve EntityFramework / SQLite in Debug mode?

Comment: You can try a clean project before you deploy, and don't use any "live" code updates while debugging.  And you don't mention how large the table(s) are, but having some slow performance is a great "code smell" that perhaps some indexing on some of the columns used for critera is a great idea. In other words, even with good performance as "non debug mode", this is still a great "code smell" that queries used may well be able to benefit by some indexing on columns used for the SQL criteria.  Also, keep in mind often it not the speed of the SQL engine, but the slower display of such data.

Comment: I have two questions. Are you 100% sure that the bottleneck is the EF core? Second question - if you do not use "step over" and instead put a breakpoint after the EF core function, do you see performance improvement?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal aww yes. This is the first thing that comes to my mind, when I want to speed up my app that is storing data (inserts). Adding some indexes. Even more justified to do it, when it is, and I quote here, "lightning fast" in release.